# making smooth when expand box search

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have simple code expand box when searc button clicked
here html code

```
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();"><img src="images/search.png"></a>
<div id="toggleText" style="display: none;">
<form>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="search">
</form> 
</div>
```

N my js code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";

}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";

}
} 
</script>
```

working well, but I want effect smooth when expand, help me thanks

Comment: With or without jQuery ?

Comment: u can give me both, with or without jquery, it will be fine for me. thanks

Comment: I suggest you to read the answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094141/make-div-expand-smoothly).

Comment: I just want edit my code above on javascript, still possible or no. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First set your **css** as this (you can change transition's duration):

```
#toggleText {
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
            transition: all .25s ease;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

#toggleText.focused {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Then change your **HTML** to this:

```
<button id="displayText"><img src="images/search.png"></button>
<div id="toggleText">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="search">
    </form> 
</div>
```

Then change your **javascript** to this and **add jQuery library**:

```
$("#displayText").click(function() {
    $("#toggleText").toggleClass("focused");
});
```

Comment: @WildaSagita Did you remove ``display: none;`` on ``#toggleText`` ?

Comment: @WildaSagita I updated the answer, this should work !

Comment: working well but there is space before click button because of box search

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ehd5n0tx/1/

I want search box in the left side of button search when clicked

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at css transitions, these are really smooth. 
Rather than display none / block, use either opacity or max-width.

With max-width, you set it to 0, and then whatever width you want, and apply a transition so you can set how quick it moves, the delay etc.  This way it will slide out sideways...

Or you can set the opacity to 0 and then 1, and it will fade in.

An example I just did is the form in the header on this eBay store, you can inspect the code to see how I did it and tweak it to suit..

[Dune eBay Store Link](http://stores.ebay.co.uk/dunelondon)

Comment: I just want edit my code above on javascript, still possible or no. thanks :)